# Querying SharePoint list via SOAP only returning first page of view

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, soap, caml

I'm trying to retrieve all items in a list, but I'm only getting the first 50 items (the first page of the default view). Ultimately I'd like to pull all items from the list into an array that I can sort and parse to output statistics in a series of formatted XSLTs, but let's solve our first hurdle first.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="/sites/mySite/Resources/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>myList</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Team_x0020_Assigned' /> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "/sites/mySite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

    function processResult(xData, status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Team_x0020_Assigned") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a rowLimit set on the view, you can override that by adding

```
<rowLimit>1000</rowLimit>
```

To the GetListItems parameters.

Note though SharePoint 2010 can throttle your request, and not return more than 5000 or 20000 (for Admins) items. These settings can be changed in Central Admin's Web Application settings.

As an aside, if you haven't done so yet, you may want to look into using the XSLT List view web part.

Comment: There's a reason why I haven't used the XSLT List View - I'm not allowed to use SharePoint Designer. Crazy I know, but it's a fact. I'm having to do all my jQuery, javascript, and HTML development in notepad.

Comment: I noticed another oddity - I set the limit to 20000 records to be sure I would get the full list. I inserted a counter into my loop that writes the records to the page, and output the counter total at the end. The counter printed 8999 records; there are 8062 records in the list. Could it be picking up deleted records or something else?

Comment: If you're using the same credentials and view, you should see the same records, you could try listing the ID field and compare.